# Motherboard rated ram is 1333 and 2000(O.C.)?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a RAM question...This is my mobo...

http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A89GTD_PROUSB3/

And it says it is rated for DDR 1333, and DDR 2000 O.C.

First of all, I would have to assume that OC stands for Over Clocked, so is there any reason to worry I could fry the board if I put in 2000?

Second, it doesn't explicitly say it supports 1600, so does that mean I REALLY can't use it?

And I guess third is there really a huge performance difference between 1333 and 1600?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/248286/does-this-mean-that-i-must-overclock-or-simply-can-overclock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Yes, OC stands for overclocking
- Of, course you can use 1600Mhz RAM (If you RAM supports it)
- No, there is no difference between 1333Mhz and 1600MHz you will notice. See this chart [link.](http://www.computerbase.de/artikel/arbeitsspeicher/2011/test-welcher-speicher-fuer-sandy-bridge/32/#abschnitt_performancerating)(It is german, nevertheless you will understand it.)
- Never forget timings, they matter as much as speed does.

**The most important question is, if your motherboard supports the RAM module you want to use in general. You can check that on list from the asus [link](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A89GTD_PROUSB3/#MSL) you posted or on several forums on the internet.**
(You will see that the PDF even lists 1600/1866/2000 Mhz RAM.)

Comment: So, which is better 7-7-7-21 or 9-9-9-24?

Comment: @jcreamer898 lower timings (7-7-7-21) and higher clocks(e.g.: 1866MHz) are better

Answer (score 2):

DDR3 2000(O.C.) means that you can use a DDR3 2000 on your motherboard but you have to set the speed/timing and other RAM settings manually in the BIOS. Otherwise it will just operate at the 1333 speed (down clocked)